# Outlook - option to run rule only on this pc missing

Tags: ms-office

I'm using **Outlook** version 16.64, I'd like to create a rule that runs only on this pc but the option seems to be missing in the Mac client, is there any solution for this?

Comment: Don't rules run locally anyway unless you are connected to an Exchange server?

Comment: @nohillside just asked, I confirm you that the accounts are connected to an exchange server. On Windows there's an option to run the rule only locally even if the account is connected to an Exchange Server, I was hoping to find a way to do the same on Mac